# nginx: how to redirect a domain name based request to a specific IP so they can't bypass a WAF

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location, hosts

I am sorry in advance if this has been covered elsewhere, as my search-fu didn't uncover it.

I want to know how, or if it is even possible, to redirect a domain name based request received by nginx to the correct IP address, so that it ignores any local hosts file overrides. In this scenario, I don't want to drop all requests that try avoid a SaaS based WAF, but rather send them to the appropriate IP.

Obviously, there is the argument that if the request isn't using the IP provided by proper DNS lookup methods, you don't to respond to it and drop/reject it. Also, I'd rather not rely on the security by obscurity method and change the existing public IP due to the associated ripples of downtime, etc.

Thank you for your time,
Al